# How to send testng report through email in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, testng

I need to send a testng report through email in Jenkins after the job is completed, but the name of the report changes each time the test is started. How can I send the latest report? I looked online but can only find tutorials with similar report names only. The naming convention of the report is: the name of the program_the date it started_and the time it started on (Ex: Program1_Tue_Oct_09_13-16-36_EDT_2018). Also will the report send as an attachment or will it be posted as a report content on the email? I was thinking of somehow adding like a regular expression to look for the latest file?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to install the Email-ext plugin?  This has a lot of options...

`Jenkins System configuration page> Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins`

Then, in your build:

Click the ‘Add post-build action’ drop-down.

Select the ‘E-mail Notification’ value.

Enter the recipient email id in the ‘E-mail Notification’ box and select the checkbox next to the ‘Send e-mail for every unstable build’ option.

Click the ‘Add post-build action’ drop-down and select the ‘Editable Email Notification’ value.

Fill the ‘Editable Email Notification’ fields.

Click the ‘Advance Settings…’ button in the ‘Editable Email Notification’ box.

Comment: Yes I have used that and it works successfully (sending success or failure emails), but I am not sure how I can add a testng report as an attachement

Comment: I have done that, so in the attachments section, I have specified the location of my testng report, but is there a way where I can specify choose from the latest report created so that after every job, it sends the latest report

Answer (score -1):

Just import the generated JUnit report using the JUnit plugin. Example:

```
junit 'target/surefire-reports/junitreports/*.xml'
```

[image: Example email screenshot]

Comment: The questioner is asking about testng report and not junit