# How To send test report from jenkins by email

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, phpunit

I've been trying to send my phpunit unit test report by email in my jenkins pipeline but i wasn't capable.
my test result is and xml file and when i tried converting it to html nothing informative was displayed. Is there any one who is familiar with this task ?

Comment: Please see if https://stackoverflow.com/a/52727950/924036 can be usefull for you issue.

Comment: @KajHejer it may work if i'm using freestyle job but i'm using a pipeline . but it can help if make a freestyle job and call it from my pipeline . tahnk you !!